# Continuous ontouchmove?

Tags: javascript, android, mousemove, onmousemove, touchmove

How do I make this work on my Android mobile continuously, similarly to the way it works on my PC? Currently it doesn't:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
(function() {
  document.onmousemove = handleMove; // for PC
  document.ontouchmove = handleMove; // for Mobile
  function handleMove(event) {
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = event.pageX + "/" + event.pageY;
  }
})();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On pc theres [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) and on mobile [TouchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/el/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent).
Create a separate function to handle mobile events.

```
function handleMobile(event) {
 document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = event.touches[0].pageX + "/" + event.touches[0].pageY;
}
```